# Django: Handle migrations created in site-packages for a custom Group field

Tags: python, django

I require a `description` field added to the `django.contrib.auth.models.Group`, so I used this solution (if there is a better way please let me know):

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

Group.add_to_class('description', models.TextField(max_length=250, default=""))
```

Unfortunately this creates a migration in:

```
site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0013_group_description.py
```

This is the migration:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='group',
            name='description',
            field=models.TextField(default='', max_length=250),
        ),
    ]
```

This can't be checked into source code since it's in the python site-packages location.

I managed to find the [MIGRATION_MODULES setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-MIGRATION_MODULES), but unfortunately I don't wish to move all of the `auth` app's migration to a new dir (django comes with 12 migrations already for `auth`, and may ship more in the future.

No idea how to solve this problem. It really makes deployment a nightmare.